# Node name wasn't found (2000) error while binding mac to AD

Tags: macos, active-directory, kerberos, macos-mojave

I have previously binded my **MAC (Mojave) to AD (Windows server 2012 R2)** successfully and later unbinded it from AD and again I am trying to bind it to the same AD and I am getting **Name server wasn't found(2000)** issue and when I googled this issue I see people suggesting to sync time and I even synched the time manually and still it didn't work. I even tried to join it from terminal using `dsconfigad` command and it is of no help, and yeah I have added the IP of server as DNS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the solution, as I was trying to sync time in AD and my MAC machine manually this issue is persisting. So, the solution to this is to sync time by configuring the AD and the MAC client machine to same time server i.e by activating NTP server on windows AD and synching it to a time server and then synching MAC machine to the same time server in my case I synched both AD and MAC client to `time.windows.com`

Follow the [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/816042/how-to-configure-an-authoritative-time-server-in-windows-server) in oder to configure NTP time server on windows AD

In order to sync time to a server in MAC go to `system preferences < Data&Time` and now type in `time server name or IP` in `set time and date automatically field`.

[image]